# How do I load Python sklearn one hot encoder in golang?

Tags: python, go, scikit-learn, porting, one-hot-encoding

I fit a [one hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in Python. I can save it using pickle or [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html) for instance.
I wonder if I can load it in golang to preprocess my data.

```
import (
"io"
"os"
"github.com/hydrogen18/stalecucumber"
prep "github.com/pa-m/sklearn/preprocessing"
"gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat"
)

func main() {

var ohe prep.OneHotEncoder
oheFilePath := "one_hot_encoder.pkl"
var r io.Reader
r, _ = os.Open(oheFilePath)
stalecucumber.UnpackInto(&ohe).From(stalecucumber.Unpickle(r))
}
```

Then I would like to one-hot encode my string vector :

```
input := []string{"ios", "US"}
```

So I would have done something like that

```
ohe.Transform(input)
```

But the Transform function takes two mat.Matrix as input, and I can't define a matrix of strings, and I also have only one input (I don't encode any labels).